# Is every Abelian group isomorphic to the external direct product of two cyclic groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

> Is every Abelian group isomorphic to the external direct product of two cyclic groups?

I know that this statement holds true for finite cyclic or non cyclic groups, like $U(n)$ for example, but I am not sure if it's true for infinite abelian groups. So I tired to find a counter example,  by assuming there is an isomorphism between $\Bbb R$ and the external product of $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z$! But I don't know if $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ is cyclic.

And also the order of both of them isnt the same, though both are infinite! I am confused on these two things , maybe an example and explanation would make things clear ?

Comment: The product of two cyclic groups is countable, while $\Bbb R$ is not.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic, with generator $1$. $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ is not cyclic.

Answer (score 16):

Cyclic groups are at most countable, so the direct product of two cyclic groups is at most countable.  So $\mathbb{R}$, which is uncountable, can't be the direct product of two cyclic groups.

But actually the statement isn't true for finite groups either.  Consider the direct product of three copies of $\mathbb{Z}_2$.  This is not the direct product of any two cyclic groups.

Comment: And another example for the finite case is that the two copies of Z4 can't be expressed as an external product of two cyclic groups ?! I hope i am getting this right this time!!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the two copies of Z4."

Comment: I am sorry, i meant to say " the external direct product of two copies of Z4 " ?!

Comment: Well if by Z4 you mean the cyclic group of order 4, then certainly the direct product of two of them is the direct product of two cyclic groups.

Comment: Oh, i get it , its already an external product of two cyclic groups, but if we were looking at 3 copies of a cyclic group of order 4 then that wouldn't be a direct product of two cyclic groups(Since the orders are not relatively prime).

Answer (score 6):

Your initial assumption is incorrect.   There are lots and lots of finite abelian groups which aren't products of *two* cyclic groups.

Secondly,  $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$ is not cyclic.   If it were, then any homomorphic image would be cyclic.   But $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$ is not cyclic.

(Interestingly enough,  there is only one infinite cyclic group,  up to isomorphism.   That's $\Bbb Z$.)

Comment: so if i took Z4 ( a cyclic group of order 4 and abelian) as a counter example for the finite case, it definitely can't be expressed as an external product of two cyclic groups, can it?

Comment: Well, it's cyclic so, I guess you could "cheat" a little and write $\Bbb Z_1\times \Bbb Z_4$.  I mainly had in mind direct products of _more than_ two cyclic groups.